# Can I access a local manual/language reference in VS 2022

Tags: c#

Can I access local help files in VS C# (those things will mean something to a programmer).? Even if it's just a lookup of a command. I used to be able to do it with Visual Studio, back in the ninties, I'd highlight a word and tap a function button, and the manual would open on the correct page. I needed to install MSDN, back then, is it possible today?

I clicked 'help' but it opened a web page, and I want local help.

Comment: Did you install local documentation?

Comment: Can't remember, where would it show up?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/help-viewer/installation?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Go to Add or Remove Programs, find Visual Studio, click to "modify", and that should give you all the options to install. If there's local documentation then this is how you'd install it.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try and learn how to access the help files, regards, Dave.